# Extract ADAM schema

Tags: active-directory, adam

I have been asked to extract the schema information in my client's ADAM setup. I need to get a full list of attributes along with whether the attribute is mandatory or optional. Is there a tool which can help me get just the schema?

The other task the client needs is to extract all the data in their ADAM setup, but I believe CSVDE can do that.

I have never worked with ADAM before, so any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with ADAM is quite the same as working with AD.

You can export your schema using :

```
ldifde -f schema.ldf -d "CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=SILOGIX-ESS01,DC=local"
```

Where `"CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=SILOGIX-ESS01,DC=local"` comes from the RooTDSE entry `schemaNamingContext`.

You should use [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/), this tool allow you to graphicaly analyse your schema.